# How do I retrieve a JSF component value by using EL?

Tags: jsf, binding, components, seam

Before going on, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705399/how-can-i-pass-a-form-field-as-a-action-parameter-by-using-seam-framework)

It's JSF form is shown again as follows:

```
<f:view>
    <h:form>
        <div>
            <label>Id</label>
            <input type="text" name="accountId"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Amount</label>
            <input type="text" name="amount"/>
        </div>
        <h:commandButton value="Withdraw" action="#{accountService.withdraw(param.accountId, param.amount)}"/>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
```

Notice that I have used `<input type="text" name="amount">` instead of `<h:inputText id="amount">`. **In order to retrieve its value** by using Seam EL resolver, I use `param.amount`.

It happens that if I use `<input type="text"` and something goes wrong on server side, I need to show the page again. So its submitted value **is not retrieved** because it is a plain html code. Because of that, I need to use a `<h:inputText` JSF component instead.

So the question is: How do I retrieve a `<h:inputText` JSF component value **by using Expression Language**?

Comment: To start, your question was fairly confusing. It look like that the Seam story is completely irrelevant here. In the future please post the JSF code you **actually** have and tell what exactly you want to do with **your** code.

Comment: This makes also no sense. In plain JSP/Servlet you could have used `<input type="text" name="foo" value="${param.foo}">` for that.

Comment: I strongly recommend to get yourself through a decent JSF book/tutorial to understand how JSF works "under the hoods". Also learning "plain vanilla" JSP/Servlet would help a lot in understanding it. You're making assumptions and are trying to break JSF's ideology by taking all its work over in your own hands. Sorry if I sound harsh, but that's the truth.

Comment: @BalusC. You said: You're making assumptions and are trying to break JSF's ideology by taking all its work over in your own hands. Sorry but i am not making assumption. If Seam supports provides parameterized method-binding and i can use this feature, what is wrong ?

Comment: Oh you **are** using Seam? I provided an answer which does the Seam way but then you were commenting that you need `FacesContext.getApplication().SOMETHING`? This is just confusion galore.

Comment: As you know BalusC, There is an implicit facesContext object: The FacesContext instance for the current request. Ok. So i think i can retrieve a Component value by using this implicit object. Nothing else.

Comment: Yes I know that. But the whole approach is in my eyes plain flawed and your question wasn't formulated very clear.

Comment: @BalusC. Although i read english very well, i have some limitation when writing in english language - I am a non-native english speaker. So feel free to edit my own question/answer when necessary - you have more than 10k reputation. Sorry any mis­under­standing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The JSF client ID's are prepended by the cliend ID of parent `UINamingContainer` components (e.g. `h:form`, `h:dataTable`, `f:subview`). If you check the generated HTML source in your webbrowser (rightclick, view source), then you should see them. The `id` and `name` of the generated input elements are prepended with the `id` of the parent form. You need to use the same name as key in the parameter map. As the separator character, the colon `:`, is an "illegal" character in EL, you need to use the brace notation `param['foo:bar']` to retrieve them.

```
<f:view>
    <h:form id="account">
        <div>
            <label>Id</label>
            <h:inputText id="id" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Amount</label>
            <h:inputText id="amount" />
        </div>
        <h:commandButton value="Withdraw" 
            action="#{accountService.withdraw(param['account:id'], param['account:amount'])}"/>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
```

Without Seam-EL-like method parameters (you apparently don't want/have it), you can also access them in the request parameter map using the client ID's as keys:

```
public void withDraw() {
    Map<String, String> map = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getRequestParameterMap();
    String id = map.get("account:id");
    String amount = map.get("account:amount");
    // ...
}
```

Needless to say that this is nasty. Just do it the normal JSF way, bind the values with bean properties.

**Edit:** as per the final question which you have edited:

> *So the question is: how do i retrieve a `<h:inputText` JSF component value by using Expression Language ?*

This is already answered before. Use the **JSF-generated** name as parameter name. This is usually in the pattern of `formId:inputId` where `formId` is the `id` of the parent `UIForm` component and the `inputId` is the `id` of the `UIInput` component. Check the generated HTML output for the exact name of the generated `<input type="text">` field. To obtain the parameter value, use the brace notation `['name']`, because you cannot use the colon `:` in EL as in `${param.formId:inputId}`.

Thus:

```
#{param['formId:inputId']}
```

Comment: Hm, this was your own answer and this was supposed to work? Well, I can only hint to check the generated HTML output to see if the names are right and/or if they are available in the request parameter map.

Comment: So you're saying that you *actually* have a `h:inputText` in your JSF page and not `<input>`? This way you need to give it (and the parent form) an `id` and get the param with the generated client ID as key. I'll edit my answer soon.

Comment: They are in the request parameter map. Have you for instance debugged its contents? `System.out.println(requestParameterMap);` so that you can see them and the patterns?

Comment: @BalusC - I think it is worth pointing out that: __A)__ the parameter used by a component is an implementation detail of the renderer; __B)__ the exact form of the `clientId` is an implementation detail (JSF 2 lets you change the delimiter, for example).

Comment: @BalusC If possible, see my own answer

Answer (score 1):

The parameter names/ids for `inputText` are encapsulated by the control renderer and are, ultimately, an implementation detail. In practice, they use the [`clientId`](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/10/jsf-working-with-component-identifiers.html). There should be no need to read these directly from the parameter map; use value binding to push them into the model and read them from there.

You can read values directly from the component using EL by binding the component to a managed bean. For simplicity, here's one bound to the request scope:

```
<!-- bind a UIComponent to the request map as "foo" -->
<h:inputText binding="#{requestScope.foo}" />
<!-- read value from a UIComponent that implements ValueHolder -->
#{requestScope.foo.value}
```

But, generally, there is no advantage to this over:

```
<!-- bind a value to the request map as "foo" -->
<h:inputText value="#{requestScope.foo}" />
<!-- read value from the request scope -->
#{requestScope.foo}
```

To avoid polluting the request map (which might result in collisions across views), use a managed bean to namespace/encapsulate your values rather than using the request scope directly.

Answer (score 0):

Although i can retrieve JSF component value through its client identifier, There are some drawback as follows:

1. According to McDowell's answer, The client identifier is an implementation detail
2. The client identifier can differ from the component identifier when there is more than one naming container in the control hierarchy. (JSF in Action book)

So if you do not want rely on client identifier, you may implement your own ElResolver as follows:

```
public class ComponentIdResolver extends ELResolver {

    public Object getValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
        if (base instanceof UIComponent && property instanceof String) {
            UIComponent r = ((UIComponent) base).findComponent((String) property);

            if (r != null) {
                context.setPropertyResolved(true);

                return r;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Now i can use something like (Notice withdraw method)

```
<h:inputText id="accountId" />
<h:inputText id="amount" />
<h:commandButton value="Withdraw" action="#{accountService.withdraw(view.accountId.value, view.amount.value)}"/>
```

view is a implicit JSF object (similar to FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot())

Then register your ELResolver as shown below (faces-config.xml)

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>br.com.view.resolver.ComponentIdResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

If you want to know a good insight about ElResolver see [Extending the Java EE Unified Expression Language with a Custom ELResolver](http://java.sun.com/mailers/techtips/enterprise/2006/TechTips_Aug06.html#1)

regards,